# Audio clip not playing in react component on page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, react-hooks

I have the following react component which is attached to all pages of the site, which should play an audio clip for 10 seconds when the site loads and thereafter whenever the user navigates to any page. The user can also use a button to continue listening to the music after the 10 second clip finishes. This mostly works fine except the music is not playing when the site first loads (there after it is fine).

I have tried various things including adding an event listener to the audio element to listen for the "canplaythrough" event, in case the file being played had not fully loaded...this did not correct the issue. I have set various console logs to see that that a file is being referenced and volume is set to 1 etc; which all return expected values.

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import audioFiles from "../data/audioFiles";
import "./SoundClip.css";

function SoundClip() {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const audioRef = useRef(null);
  const randomFileRef = useRef(null);

  const togglePlay = () => {
    if (isPlaying) {
      audioRef.current.pause();
    } else {
      // Set a new random file to play
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * audioFiles.length);
      const randomFile = audioFiles[randomIndex];
      randomFileRef.current = randomFile;
      
      // Set the audio source to the new file
      audioRef.current.src = `${randomFile.path}`;
      audioRef.current.volume = 1;
      audioRef.current.play();
    }
    setIsPlaying(!isPlaying);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    audioRef.current.addEventListener("ended", () => setIsPlaying(false));
    
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * audioFiles.length);
    const randomFile = audioFiles[randomIndex];
    randomFileRef.current = randomFile;

    audioRef.current.src = `${randomFile.path}`;
    const audio = audioRef.current;

    audioRef.current.play(); // play the audio on page load
    setIsPlaying(true);

    // set the initial volume to 1
    if (audioRef.current.volume != null) {
      audioRef.current.volume = 1;
    }

    // start the fade-out effect after 9 seconds (1000 milliseconds = 1 second)
    setTimeout(() => {
      let fadeOutInterval = setInterval(() => {
        if (audioRef.current != null) {
          // decrease the volume by 0.1 every 100 milliseconds
          if (audioRef.current.volume > 0) {
            audioRef.current.volume = Math.max(audioRef.current.volume - 0.1, 0);
          }
          if (audioRef.current.volume <= 0) {
            // stop the interval and pause the audio when the volume reaches 0
            clearInterval(fadeOutInterval);
            audioRef.current.pause();
            setIsPlaying(false);
          }
        }
      }, 100);
    }, 9000); // 9 seconds in milliseconds

    return () => {
      // reset the volume to 1 when the component unmounts
      if (audio != null) {
        audio.volume = 1;
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <audio ref={audioRef} src="" />
      <button onClick={togglePlay}>{isPlaying ? 'Pause' : 'Play'}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SoundClip;
```

Comment: It's possible the browser disables audio on page load

Comment: 'Sites can play sound' is enabled on my browser; I dont think there is a specific setting that stops sound being played on first load of the site.